# Present Value of flow of profits with constant interest rate

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth, endogenous-growth

I'm studying Schumpeterian Models of Quality Ladders from the Barro's book (Ch.7).

I have problems in getting the derivation of equation $(7.13)$ as follows
[image]

The basic idea of those models is: when an innovation arrives, in the form of quality improvements of the existing product varieties, (randomly) in the $j$ industry at time $t_{k_j}$ the monopolist will enjoy a stream of profits equal to $\pi(k_j)$ until a new (different innovator) will invent a better quality of the product variety $j$ at time $t_{k_{j+1}}$. Once this will occur, the profits of the previous monopolist will go to zero. So, $T(k_j)$ is the time span when the monopolist making an innovation at $t_{k_j}$ makes positive profits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mathematical steps to arrive from 7.12 to 7.13 are the following:

\begin{aligned}
& V\left(k_j\right)=\int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} \pi(k) e^{-\frac{v-t_{k}}{v-t_{k}} \cdot \int_{t_k}^v r(\omega) d w}
\end{aligned}
Considering that
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{t_k}^v r d w=r\left(v-t_k\right)
\end{aligned}
We have:
\begin{aligned}
& \pi(k) \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} e^{-r\left(v-t_k\right)} d v =\\
&= \pi(k)\left[\frac{e^{-r\left(v-t_k\right)}}{-r}\right]_{v=t_k}^{t_k+1}= \\
& =\pi(k)\left(\frac{-e^{-r\left(t_{k+1}-t_k\right)}+1}{r}\right)= \\
& =\pi(k) \frac{1-e^{-r T_k}}{r}. \\
&
\end{aligned}